# How to force CFileDialog to access path longer than 256 characters?

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, cfiledialog

According to [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is possible to create and use files with names exceeding 256 chars. I have actually tested this before, and it works fine, also for Unicode charaters.

But my question is there any possibility to force class CFileDialog to accept and show folders, where path is longer than 256 characters?

Changes at OFN structure, before calling DoModal() function, doesn't give any affect:

```
FileDialog.GetOFN().lpstrInitialDir = _T("\\\\?\\P:");
FileDialog.GetOFN().nMaxFile=1024;
FileDialog.GetOFN().nMaxFileTitle=256;
if(FileDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
  DoSomething()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try entering the file names with `\\?\`? Not the OFN structure, but what you as a user enter in the dialog. Try pasting a very long full path that way, and see what happens.

Comment: @satuon - this throws me warning "\\?\p:\something The above path is invalid.". I will try to overload `CFileDialog` class and `OnFolderChange` method to include "\\?\" prefix when user changes the directory.

Comment: @satuon - i've tried, but there is no option to change current folder path in CFileDialog. Method `OnFolderChange` is invoked **after** moving to another folder, so the dialog can't actually move to folder with path exceeding 256 chars. in `OFN` structure there is also no variable which handles current directory.